# Swift : Can't integrate facebook and G+ in same project

Tags: facebook, swift, google-plus

I created a sample project for integrating(Login) Facebook and G+ in Swift in separate project. It worked fine.
But,
when I tried to include G+ and Facebook in same Sample project, and 
set "Other Linker Flag" : "-ObjC"(For G+ integration) and run I got this error
[image]

If I remove "Other Linker Flag" then I get this error : 
[image]

Please provide the solution how can I integrate facebook and G+ in swift in same project?
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That I integrate both G+ and Facebook its working fine. Please give some more detail about your error and what method did you follow for G+ integration

Comment: @Manikandan : I have added more images of my code. You can refer from their. If you need anything else to know, do tell me.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was, I added all the framework in my project. When I remove FBAudienceNetwork.framework from my project than all errors disappeared and it works fine. But I think it could be problem if we are using it along with G+.